# Multi-Attach error for persistent volume for EBS in EKS

Tags: amazon-eks, amazon-ebs, persistent-volumes

1. Created Storage Class for AWS EKS for EBS

   ```
   kind: StorageClass
   apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
   metadata:
     name: ebs-sc
   provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
   volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
   ```
2. Created Persistent volume Claim with ReadWriteOnce

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
   metadata:
     name: ebs-claim
   spec:
     accessModes:
       - ReadWriteOnce
     storageClassName: gp2
     resources:
       requests:
         storage: 4Gi
   ```
3. Deploy app using Deployment. Everything worked fine. PV got created and got claimed by PVC. 2 pods started.
4. Tried to delete one POD but got below error while starting new POD
   Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-5a4ee84b-7afb-40cf-8596-65b76829d540" Volume is already used by pod(s)
   Tried PVC with ReadWriteMany but PV failed to create PV
   Understood that ReadWriteMany is not supported by EBS and ReadWriteOnce doesnt allow to scale, delete or rollout restart.

Could you please suggest any solution or WA?

Comment: Related to this [open issue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html) on aws-ebs-csi-driver repository

Answer (score 0):

As you may already be aware, that as the error suggests there are multiple pods that try to mount this EBS PV, which can be mount only to a single POD at any moment. While you delete the POD you may see that there's another instance of the POD that tries to come up. You'd ideally need to delete the deployment and redeploy for a single instance of your POD to use your EBS PV.

Also EBS PV would bound you to a single Zone.

> As part of your deployment, you could scale down the deployment that
> uses EBS PV and your new deployment should scale up the deployment.

Comment: What about a solution that involved no downtime? This is hardly ideal in a production context

Comment: For production workloads and services that need roll out deployments, scaling up, using EFS volumes or NFS volumes would be ideal, where it supports multi attach.